# What is the reason that the burial place of Lady Fatimah (as) still concealed?

Tags: grave, fatima-zahra

**What is the reason that the burial place of Lady Fatimah (a.s.) still concealed?**

I want to know about the grave of Lady Fatimah (a.s.), since some people believe that there have been some reasons that it is not clear where she is. Thus what is/are the reason(s) that her (as) grave is hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause behind the hiding of the grave of Fatimah(as) was done by her command and will, it is showing the protest to the movement that had begun after the Prophet's (pbuh) death regarding the caliphate, and the trampling of rights and the reality.[1](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/en6354)

Secondly her grave is a barrier that doesn't let the change of the history of Islam advent and prevents from some claiming that  shi didn't have any protest to the circumstances then about the caliphate.

---

*[1](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/en6354) see: Ibn Abil-Hadid, Sharh Nahjil-Balaghah, vol. 16; Sheikh Abdullah Naser, Mihnatu Fatimah ba'da Wafati Rasulillah (s) (Nusus Tarikhiyyah Min Masadiril-Sunnatil-Mu'tamadah),pp.197-206.*

---

**Source:**

- [http://islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/en6354)